# Как вывести из pivot table в typeOrm?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

есть таблица orders - id, username
eсть таблица people - id, title, description
между ними связь многие-ко-многим таблица order_people - id, order_id, people_id, price

как через query builder вывести вот такую структуру

id из orders

- title из people, price из order_people
- title 2 из people, price 2 из order_people

начал вот так писать, но что-то не могу сообразить как правильно построить запрос

```
const queryBuilder = this.orderRepository.createQueryBuilder('o');

    queryBuilder
      .leftJoin('o.orderToPeople', 'people')
      .select([
        'o.id as id',
        'o.phone as phone',
        'people.*'
      ])
      .orderBy('o.createdAt', pageOptionsDto.order ?? 'DESC')
      .skip(pageOptionsDto.skip)
      .take(pageOptionsDto.take);

    const query = await queryBuilder.getRawMany();
```